# Integrate Google Apps LTI to canvas lms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-apps, lti, canvas-lms

Integrate External tool in `canvas lms` using [this](https://www.eduappcenter.com/apps/641?filter_text=google%20a#.XEG-uXUzbCI),

```
Getting error - while(1);{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"unknown client"}
```

Is there any way to integrate own google credential, not self generated by canvas?

Comment: Old now... but are you self-hosted? Many of these LTI tools unfortunately only work with a Canvas-hosted instance.